# Radial gradient background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to produce a basic radial gradient background, but without success. I managed to get a linear gradient working as shown with the code below, but I have no idea how to make it radial with different colours - like in the image below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations ...
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you are doing this way for learning purpose thats fine but if you are using this for design purpose I recommend to design it in sketch3 and use it as UIImage

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043534/circular-cagradientlayer-mask may help you.

Comment: @sriramhegde The background needs to dynamically Change. An image wouldn't help. Thanks.

Comment: Please note on this old question, **this is now very easy** - answer down below!

Comment: (obviously never use an image for a gradient in an iPhone app! the gpu is incredibly good at making gradients; an image will look horrible, won't scale, and is very non-performant.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have a look at my implementation of RadialGradientLayer, and feel free to modify it

```
class RadialGradientLayer: CALayer {

   override init(){

        super.init()

        needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
    }

     init(center:CGPoint,radius:CGFloat,colors:[CGColor]){

        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.colors = colors

        super.init()

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init()

    }

    var center:CGPoint = CGPointMake(50,50)
    var radius:CGFloat = 20
    var colors:[CGColor] = [UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 237/255, blue: 33/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor , UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 179/255, blue: 108/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor]

    override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {

        CGContextSaveGState(ctx)

        var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        var locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

        var gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, [0.0,1.0])

        var startPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.height)
        var endPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)

        CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradient, center, 0.0, center, radius, 0)

    }

}
```

In my case I needed it with two colors only and if you need more colors you need to modify `location` array declared in `drawInContext`. Also after creating object from this class don't forget to call its `setNeedsDisplay()` otherwise it wont work. Also sometimes I needed different size gradients so thats why you have to pass radius parameter in initializer and the center point of your gradient

Comment: This is how I created the object in the viewDidLoad but It did not work for one reason or the other. @zellb.
        var screenCentre = CGPointMake(100, 100)
        let innerColour = UIColor.redColor() as! CGColor
        let outterColour = UIColor.greenColor() as! CGColor
       var  radialGradientBackground = RadialGradientLayer(center: screenCentre, radius: CGFloat(50.0), colors: [innerColour, outterColour])
        radialGradientBackground.frame = self.view!.bounds
        self.view!.layer.insertSublayer(radialGradientBackground, atIndex: 0)
        
        self.view!.setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: setNeedsDisplay must be called on radialGradientBackground and not in view

Comment: Sweet. Worked well @zellb. Thanks. ;)

Comment: @Gugulethu glad to hear that

Comment: I have an issue with this one, if you add it in viewDidLoad, then you can notice the layer being added to view, which causes a glitch and delay of the dispaly. any thoughts of how to avoid it happenning?

Comment: locations, startPoint and endPoint are not even used in your drawInContext

Comment: In total, this is how to make this work: 1. Construct layer: `let layer = RadialGradientLayer(center: centerPoint, radius: radius, colors: [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor])` 2. `layer.setNeedsDisplay()` 3. `layer.frame = self.view.bounds` 4. `self.view.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)` Thank you!!

Comment: @ZellB. no need to call `setNeedsDisplay` if you put `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true` within your own `init(center:...)` method instead of putting it in `override init()`.

Comment: Really, you now do this **with a simple gradient layer**, you'd never `draw` it these days.  For anyone googling here it's important to note that really old QA like this go out of date!  Simply use a gradient layer.

Answer (score 38):

## Nowadays CAGradientLayer is built-in to iOS.

## It's this easy:

For years now you simply do this:

```
class GlowBall: UIView {
    private lazy var pulse: CAGradientLayer = {
        let l = CAGradientLayer()
        l.type = .radial
        l.colors = [ UIColor.red.cgColor,
            UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
            UIColor.green.cgColor,
            UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        l.locations = [ 0, 0.3, 0.7, 1 ]
        l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        layer.addSublayer(l)
        return l
    }()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        pulse.frame = bounds
        pulse.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2.0
    }

}
```

[image]

The key lines are:

```
l.colors = [ UIColor.red.cgColor,
                UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
                UIColor.green.cgColor,
                UIColor.blue.cgColor]
l.locations = [ 0, 0.3, 0.7, 1 ]
```

Note that you can change the "stretch" as you wish ...

```
l.locations = [ 0, 0.1, 0.2, 1 ]
```

[image]

Use any colors you like

```
l.colors = [ UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor,
                    UIColor.systemPink.cgColor,
                    UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor,
                    UIColor.systemPink.cgColor,
                    UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor,
                    UIColor.systemPink.cgColor,
                    UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor,
                    UIColor.systemPink.cgColor]
                l.locations = [ 0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,1 ]
```

[image]

It's really that easy now.

## Very useful trick:

Say you want **yellow**, with a **blue band** at 0.6:

```
l.colors = [ UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
                    UIColor.blue.cgColor,
                    UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
                l.locations = [ 0, 0.6, 1 ]
```

That works fine.

```
    # yellow...
    # blue...
    # yellow...
```

But usually you do this:

```
    # yellow...
    # yellow...
    # blue...
    # yellow...
    # yellow...
```

Notice there are TWO of the yellows at each end ...

```
l.colors = [ UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
 UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
 UIColor.blue.cgColor,
 UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
 UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
```

In this way, you can control **"how wide"** the blue band is:

In this example: the blue band will be **narrow and sharp**:

```
l.locations = [ 0, 0.58, 0.6, 0.68, 1 ]
```

In this example the blue band will be **broad and soft**:

```
l.locations = [ 0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1 ]
```

That is really the secret to how you control gradients, and get the look you want.

---

### How to use ...

Notice this is - very simply - a UIView !!

```
class GlowBall: UIView { ...
```

Thus simply

1. In storyboard, place a UIView where you want
2. In storyboard, change the class to "GlowBall" instead of UIView

You're done!

Comment: yeah no problem! :) Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Great answer. I think it would be beneficial to also show how to use it.

Answer (score 23):

Here is an implementation in Swift 3 if you're just looking for a UIView radial gradient background:

```
class RadialGradientLayer: CALayer {

    var center: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
    }

    var radius: CGFloat {
        return (bounds.width + bounds.height)/2
    }

    var colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor.black, UIColor.lightGray] {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var cgColors: [CGColor] {
        return colors.map({ (color) -> CGColor in
            return color.cgColor
        })
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        ctx.saveGState()
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let locations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
        guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: cgColors as CFArray, locations: locations) else {
            return
        }
        ctx.drawRadialGradient(gradient, startCenter: center, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: center, endRadius: radius, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    }

}



class RadialGradientView: UIView {

    private let gradientLayer = RadialGradientLayer()

    var colors: [UIColor] {
        get {
            return gradientLayer.colors
        }
        set {
            gradientLayer.colors = newValue
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if gradientLayer.superlayer == nil {
            layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        }
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

}
```

Comment: Neat solution, + for easy extendibility.

Comment: How to use this in a Playground?

Comment: For anyone googling here, please note that `CAGradientLayer` now exists. You definitely don't need to `draw` these days.  It's completely built-in.  (As a detail, I believe this will crash if the array sent in has a number other than 2 items.)

Answer (score 9):

```
@IBDesignable class RadialGradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var outsideColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var insideColor: UIColor = UIColor.green

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let colors = [insideColor.cgColor, outsideColor.cgColor] as CFArray
        let endRadius = sqrt(pow(frame.width/2, 2) + pow(frame.height/2, 2))
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors, locations: nil)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.drawRadialGradient(gradient!, startCenter: center, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: center, endRadius: endRadius, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsBeforeStartLocation)
    }
}
```

See my full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42369879/1836420).

Comment: `CAGradientLayer` is now completely built-in to iOS, for years now

Answer (score 1):

A little different approach with function which takes parent view, colors, and locations as input. The function returns a subview where the layer was added. This gives the flexibility to hide/show/remove subview.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //squareView is my parent view I am going to add gradient view to it
    squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    //Add CG colors
    let colours = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.green.cgColor,UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    //Add location with same count as colors, these describe contribution in gradient from center 0 to end 1
    let locations:[NSNumber] = [0,0.6,0.8]
    //Use gradientView reference to show/hide, remove/re-add from view
    let gradientView = self.addGradientViewTo(parentView: self.squareView, colors:colours,locations: locations)
}

func addGradientViewTo (parentView:UIView,colors:[CGColor],locations:[NSNumber]) -> UIView  {
    //Create customGradientView with exact dimension of parent, add it with centering with parent
    let customGradientView = UIView()
    customGradientView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    customGradientView.frame = parentView.bounds
    parentView.addSubview(customGradientView)
    customGradientView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    customGradientView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    parentView.clipsToBounds = true

    //Create layer add it to customGradientView
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.type = .radial //Circular
    gradientLayer.opacity = 0.8
    gradientLayer.colors = colors
    gradientLayer.locations = locations
    gradientLayer.frame = customGradientView.bounds
    
    //Set start point as center and radius as 1, co-ordinate system maps 0 to 1, 0,0 top left, bottom right 1,1
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    let radius = 1.0
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: radius, y: radius)
          
    //Add layer at top to make sure its visible
    let layerCount:UInt32 = UInt32(customGradientView.layer.sublayers?.count ?? 0)
    customGradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: layerCount)
    customGradientView.layoutIfNeeded()
    
    //Use reference to show/hide add/remove gradient view
    return customGradientView
}
```