# Crop Part of CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, calayer, cashapelayer

[image: Click here to see image].

I want to crop out the Red triangle part from the **CAshapelayer**.

This is the code i used for drawing it:

[Radial Gradient background in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853859/radial-gradient-background-in-swift) and my code is:

```
let bgLayer = RadialGradientLayer(center: speed_dial_center_point, radius: speed_dial_size.width/2, colors: [UIColor.clear.cgColor,UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 0.5).cgColor],speed_scale_margin: speed_scale_margin)//CALayer()
            bgLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: rect.origin, size: speed_dial_size)
            bgLayer.contentsScale = self.layer.contentsScale
            bgLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
            backgondArc_Layer.addSublayer(bgLayer)
            self.layer.insertSublayer(backgondArc_Layer, below: speed_dial_layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add a mask layer to your gradient layer that masks out the part you want to remove.

Comment: I have given stroke color to clear color that's why it was not masking.

cropArea.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

Now after changing it to black, it works.

Comment: Drawing with clear color does nothing. It's like painting with no paint on your brush.