# How to fix inconsistent color-to-clear radial gradient layer

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

When trying to draw a radial gradient from white to clear, I obtain different results depending on whether I use `UIColor(white:alpha:)`, `UIColor.white.withAlpha.Components(alpha:)` or `UIColor.color`. How Can I get the same gradient with a clear color as with a plain color?

I order to draw a radial gradient, I have overridden the draw(context:) method (see below). My code seems to work fine when using plain colours for a gradient but works "mysteriously" when using a clear color.

```
override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
    super.draw(in: ctx)

    ctx.saveGState()
    let gradient                = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colorFill as CFArray, locations: self.locations as! [CGFloat] )
    let startPoint              = CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY )
    let endPoint                = CGPoint(x: endX , y: endY)
    let drawingOption           : CGGradientDrawingOptions = radius > 0 ? [] : .drawsAfterEndLocation

    //self.masksToBounds          = true
    if gradientType == .radial {
        ctx.drawRadialGradient(gradient!, startCenter: startPoint, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: endPoint, endRadius: self.frame.width / 2, options: drawingOption)
    } else {
        self.startPoint = startPoint
        self.endPoint   = endPoint
    }
}
```

Here's the results I obtain depending on the input colours for the gradient:

`[UIColor.white.cgColor,UIColor.black.cgColor]` 
(desired result with clear color instead of black)

[image: White to Black]

`[UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]`

[image: White to Clear]

`[UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0).cgColor]`

[image: White to White with alpha component]

`[UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0).cgColor]`

[image: Gray layer with alpha component]

Could someone can explain why I don't get the same output as with only plain colours (output I wish to obtain)?

Thanks a lot for taking the time to read and reply!

Comment: Hope it helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853859/radial-gradient-background-in-swift

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dahiya_boy. I already knew this topic and my draw method is basically the same already.

Comment: **Problem solved!** I will post an update later but to put it all in a nutshell, I came to have the confirmation that my layer was drawn twice (you can see a bit of white in the black and white picture) as I actually suspected. In my `init' method I was setting `self.colors` and `self.locations` which in fact draws the layer before the `draw(in context)` method can _redraw_ it. By way of saving the info in separate type properties, I can prevent the first drawing of the layer, hence getting the adequate result!

Answer (score 1):

The layer is not drawn only in the `draw(in context:)` method. This line of code confirms some properties had been set prior to the call of the method, which has priorly triggered the drawing of the layer **(self.locations)**:

`CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colorFill as CFArray, locations: self.locations as! [CGFloat] )`

By removing the set of self.colors and self.locations properties in the custom initializer and storing the values in Type Properties instead before calling `self.setNeedDisplay()`, the layer is only being drawn in the `draw(in context:)` method.

```html
class CustomLayer {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
    }
    
    override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    var colors    = []()
    var colorMap  = [NSNumber]()
    
    custom init() {
      colors = [color,color]
      colorMap = [0.0, 1.0]
      self.setNeedDisplay()
    }
    
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        super.draw(in: ctx)
        ctx.saveGState()
        guard let gradient          = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors as CFArray, locations: colorMap as! [CGFloat] ) else {return}
        let startPoint              = CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY )
        let endPoint                = CGPoint(x: endX , y: endY)
        self.masksToBounds          = true
        if gradientType == .radial {
            ctx.drawRadialGradient(gradient, startCenter: startPoint, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: endPoint, endRadius: self.frame.width / 2, options: drawingOption)
        } else {
            self.locations          = colorMap
            self.colors             = colors
            self.startPoint         = startPoint
            self.endPoint           = endPoint
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Cheers!