# Draw ellipse gradient in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to draw ellipse gradient in Swift.

In CSS:

```
background: radial-gradient(50% 25% at 20% 30%, #ffffff, #ff0000);
```

I expect appearance to be like following:

[image]

I know I can draw circle gradient by using `CGContext.drawRadialGradient(_:startCenter:startRadius:endCenter:endRadius:options)`.
But, I don't know how to draw **ellipse** gradient.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if this is helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854064/12830762 you need to change the code according to your need

Comment: @Niraj Thank you for your quick comment. But, the post you mentioned is not about ellipse gradient but about radial gradient. I want to know the way to draw ellipse gradient.

Comment: @Niraj I came across your answer while trying to figure this out, I just wanted to comment in case anyone else comes across this, create an ellipse CAShapeLayer and apply that ellipse shape layer as a mask to a CAGradientLayer of type .radial. It will scale properly to create an elliptical gradient, pretty neat!